# Determine which JAR file a class is from

Tags: java, jar, class, classloader

I am not in front of an IDE right now, just looking at the API specs.

```
CodeSource src = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
if (src != null) {
    URL jar = src.getLocation();
}
```

I want to determine which JAR file a class is from. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: Is there a way to do this from console? Something like `java -findjar -cp /some/path/with/libs/*.jar my.java.Class` -> `my.jar`.

Comment: @kub1x see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411760/1098603) for a way to do it from (Linux) console. I'm also preparing a javassist-based "findjar" equivalent...

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Yes. It works for all classes except classes loaded by bootstrap classloader. The other way to determine is:

```
Class klass = String.class;
URL location = klass.getResource('/' + klass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
```

As notnoop pointed out `klass.getResource()` method returns the location of the class file itself. For example:

```
jar:file:/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/String.class
file:/projects/classes/pkg/MyClass$1.class
```

The `getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` method returns the location of the jar file or CLASSPATH

```
file:/Users/home/java/libs/ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
file:/projects/classes
```

Comment: This makes assumptions abut the mapping from class name to class file.  Will it work properly for anonymous classes?  Nested classes?

Comment: This points to the url of the class not the jar itself.  The url needs to be parsed to find the jar file.

Comment: @notnoop. I have clarified the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it inspired me to answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26780355/1082681).

Comment: Which argument do you pass to `klass.getResource()` in your last example?

Comment: `getProtectionDomain()` is always returning null for me..

Answer (score 14):

Checkout the `LiveInjector.findPathJar()` from [Lombok Patcher `LiveInjector.java`](http://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok.patcher/blob/master/src/lombok/patcher/inject/LiveInjector.java).  Note that it special cases where the file doesn't actually live in a jar, and you might want to change that.

```
/**
 * If the provided class has been loaded from a jar file that is on the local file system, will find the absolute path to that jar file.
 * 
 * @param context The jar file that contained the class file that represents this class will be found. Specify {@code null} to let {@code LiveInjector}
 *                find its own jar.
 * @throws IllegalStateException If the specified class was loaded from a directory or in some other way (such as via HTTP, from a database, or some
 *                               other custom classloading device).
 */
public static String findPathJar(Class<?> context) throws IllegalStateException {
    if (context == null) context = LiveInjector.class;
    String rawName = context.getName();
    String classFileName;
    /* rawName is something like package.name.ContainingClass$ClassName. We need to turn this into ContainingClass$ClassName.class. */ {
        int idx = rawName.lastIndexOf('.');
        classFileName = (idx == -1 ? rawName : rawName.substring(idx+1)) + ".class";
    }

    String uri = context.getResource(classFileName).toString();
    if (uri.startsWith("file:")) throw new IllegalStateException("This class has been loaded from a directory and not from a jar file.");
    if (!uri.startsWith("jar:file:")) {
        int idx = uri.indexOf(':');
        String protocol = idx == -1 ? "(unknown)" : uri.substring(0, idx);
        throw new IllegalStateException("This class has been loaded remotely via the " + protocol +
                " protocol. Only loading from a jar on the local file system is supported.");
    }

    int idx = uri.indexOf('!');
    //As far as I know, the if statement below can't ever trigger, so it's more of a sanity check thing.
    if (idx == -1) throw new IllegalStateException("You appear to have loaded this class from a local jar file, but I can't make sense of the URL!");

    try {
        String fileName = URLDecoder.decode(uri.substring("jar:file:".length(), idx), Charset.defaultCharset().name());
        return new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new InternalError("default charset doesn't exist. Your VM is borked.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated to get something very simple.  I just sat down and tried what I found earlier, and it appears to work.  Just wanted some validation.

Comment: Well.  Your code doesn't handle files in bootclass paths, and Chandra's solution returns the url to the file not to the jar file, so you'll need to parse the path to find the jar file.

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
String path = <Any of your class within the jar>.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

If this contains multiple entries then do some substring operation.

Comment: I was struggling with a problem. This approach saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

```
private String resourceLookup(String lookupResourceName) {



    try {

        if (lookupResourceName == null || lookupResourceName.length()==0) {
            return "";
        }
        // "/java/lang/String.class"

        // Check if entered data was in java class name format
        if (lookupResourceName.indexOf("/")==-1) {
            lookupResourceName = lookupResourceName.replaceAll("[.]", "/");
            lookupResourceName =  "/" + lookupResourceName + ".class";
        }

        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(lookupResourceName);
        if (url == null) {
            return("Unable to locate resource "+ lookupResourceName);

        }

        String resourceUrl = url.toExternalForm();

        Pattern pattern =
            Pattern.compile("(zip:|jar:file:/)(.*)!/(.*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        String jarFilename = null;
        String resourceFilename = null;
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(resourceUrl);
        if (m.find()) {
            jarFilename = m.group(2);
            resourceFilename = m.group(3);
        } else {
            return "Unable to parse URL: "+ resourceUrl;

        }

        if (!jarFilename.startsWith("C:") ){
          jarFilename = "/"+jarFilename;  // make absolute path on Linux
        }

        File file = new File(jarFilename);
        Long jarSize=null;
        Date jarDate=null;
        Long resourceSize=null;
        Date resourceDate=null;
        if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {

            jarSize = file.length();
            jarDate = new Date(file.lastModified());

            try {
                JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file, false);
                ZipEntry entry = jarFile.getEntry(resourceFilename);
                resourceSize = entry.getSize();
                resourceDate = new Date(entry.getTime());
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                return ("Unable to open JAR" + jarFilename + "   "+resourceUrl +"\n"+e.getMessage());

            }

           return "\nresource: "+resourceFilename+"\njar: "+jarFilename + "  \nJarSize: " +jarSize+"  \nJarDate: " +jarDate.toString()+"  \nresourceSize: " +resourceSize+"  \nresourceDate: " +resourceDate.toString()+"\n";


        } else {
            return("Unable to load jar:" + jarFilename+ "  \nUrl: " +resourceUrl);

        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        return e.getMessage();
    }


}
```

Comment: The above code will find any resource on the path.  If in a Jar will find the jar print the size & date of the jar and the size and date of the resource within the jar

Answer (score 1):

With Linux, I'm using a small script to help me find in which jar a class lies that can be used in a `find -exec`:

`findclass.sh`:

```
unzip -l "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep $2 >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$1"
```

Basically, as jars are zip, `unzip -l` will print the list of class resources, so you'll have to convert `.` to `/`. You could perform the replacement in the script with a `tr`, but it's not too much trouble to do it yourself when calling the script.

The, the idea is to use `find` on the root of your classpath to locate all jars, then runs `findclass.sh` on all found jars to look for a match.

It doesn't handle multi-directories, but if you carefully choose the root you can get it to work.

Now, find which jar contains class `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils` to you un-mavenize your project (...):

```
$ find ~/.m2/repository/ -type f -name '*.jar' -exec findclass.sh {} org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils \;

.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.7/commons-lang3-3.7.jar
.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.6/commons-lang3-3.6.jar
.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.6/commons-lang3-3.6-sources.jar
$
```