# Oracle JDBC driver conflict

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, classcastexception

JBoss EAP 6.1 standlone server

Application deployed as a war file throws a runtime exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.ARRAY cannot be cast to oracle.sql.ARRAY
```

at line

```
oracle.sql.ARRAY obj = (oracle.sql.ARRAY) rs.getObject("RATINGOBJ");
```

JDBC libary included is ojdbc6.jar (WEB_INF/lib). All libraries are included in the war file and there are no "global" libaries setup on the server. I have verified no other jdbc libraries are included anywhere in the app.

In order to create a JDBC datasource, i created a deployment for ojdbc6.jar. This is the only possible source of conflict i can think of. When i remove the ojdbc6.jar from the war file, i get a ClassNotFound exception in place of the ClassCastException.

Every other part of the app works fine except this  line. How do i debug this any further?

Comment: Maybe try and run a very simple test app with only your JDBC driver as a dependency?

Comment: Does it occur only occasionally? Do you restart the server each time you redeploy the application?

Comment: Each time i deploy the app, i restart the server. I dont think it is necessary, but i do it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why loading from web-inf/lib will not work. Most likely the classloader's are different.

Do the first two steps for diagnosis. After that try one of the two alternatives below to fix the problem.
1) Check if the class loaders are the same by comparing the `rs.getObject().getClass('RATINGOBJ').getClassLoader()` and `oracle.sql.ARRAY.class.getClassLoader()`
 If you do `equals` between the two classloaders, it should return false as it looks that the classloaders are different.
Check an explanation at 
[ClassCastException when casting to the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class)

This problem has already been reported earlier in another forum at https://forums.oracle.com/message/9330314. Moving jars around in jboss will still result in same problems.

2) Find out the source jars from where the classes are getting loaded and remove the jar that you dont need. 
Find the jars for the two different classes by checking
`rs.getObject().getClass('RATINGOBJ').getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`
`oracle.sql.ARRAY.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` 
 - [Determine which JAR file a class is from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983839/determine-which-jar-file-a-class-is-from)

Possible Solutions:

a) If you need both the jars, y'll have to move the Jar of 
`rs.getObject().getClass('RATINGOBJ').getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`

and create the module as specified at http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8184.

b) If you still cant get classes to be loaded as you expect, Specify the library in jboss server library.

c) The last solution to force classes to be loaded from a particular jar is by specifying the jar in the bootclasspath.

Comment: `******* Object classloader = ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ojdbc5.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
******* Class  classloader = ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.Dispatch.war:main" from Service Module Loader
******* Object jarLoc = vfs:/content/ojdbc5.jar
******* Class  jarLoc = vfs:/content/Dispatch.war/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc5.jar
********* Classloaders are different ***********`

Printed the values you suggested. Class loaders seem different. There are 2 deployments on the server, ojdbc5.jar for creating a DataSource and the App itself which includes ojdbc5.jar

Comment: I still havent been able to locate the server library for JBoss EAP. If i remove ojdbc5.jar from WEB_INF/lib, i get ClassNotFound and if i include it. it conflicts with the same jar which i installed as a module to be used in creating the DataSource. I will try and test your possible solutions tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue using Solution A. Created a module with ojdbc6.jar. Used that to define the driver and create the datasource. Also added jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the application war to refer to this module instead of including it in the WEB-INF/lib. Classloaders are now showing the same and all seems to work well for now. What complicated matters quite a bit was that i am new to JBoss and failed to realize the differences between JBoss EAP 6 from  RedHat and JBoss AS 7. Thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have any JDBC driver JARs at the WEB-INF/lib level.  Java EE app servers need them to be at the app server level.

Move it into the default server /lib directory and see if that's better.

Comment: Isn't that only if you want the container to provide e.g. database connection pooling?  If you do everything yourself you do not have to.

Comment: True enough, but why would you use an app server and *not* use connection pooling?  Tomcat makes it a requirement now, and the JBOSS servlet/JSP engine is a fork of Tomcat.

Comment: I agree. I think its a ClassLoader  thing.

Comment: The JDBC driver included in the app is not used for connection pooling. I have a connection pool defined in the appserver level which is used for that purpose. The reason i need ojdbc6.jar in the app is to use the java.sql.ARRAY object. Does that sound right?

Comment: After seeing this answer, i moved ojdbc6.jar to JBOSS_HOME/standalone/lib and removed it from the war file (and restarted the server). Results in
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/ARRAY

When i have the ojdbc6.jar as part of the WEB-INF/lib, i get the earlier error
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.ARRAY cannot be cast to oracle.sql.ARRAY
And all this to just use the ARRAY clas in that package. I amsure i am doing something fundamemntally wrong here

Comment: I don't put it in that folder.  $JBOSS_HOME\server\default\lib is where it belongs.

Comment: @duffymo i can find no such directory on JBoss EAP 6.1

Comment: I'm looking at it right now in my local JBOSS 6.1 final.  It's the way on my JBOSS 5.1.2 at work, too.

Comment: @duffymo i am using the Enterprise version from Redhat. That could be the reson