# h2o: distinguish between local and hadoop instance

Tags: python, hadoop, h2o

Is there a way from the Python client to distinguish the cases where H2O was launched locally through `java -jar h2o.jar` and where it was launched on hadoop through `hadoop -jar h2odriver.jar`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work and have not tested it, maybe you can combine the answers from:
[Calling Java from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python)
and [Determine which JAR file a class is from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983839/determine-which-jar-file-a-class-is-from) to call the code for the latter from Python and determine the location of a known class?

Comment: I'm afraid this method will tell me which Java was launched by my Python client. What I'd like to know is which Java was used to launch H2O. I'm accessing this H2O instance thanks to the Python client talking to the REST API.

Comment: BTW, if it solves my problem, it's OK to directly query the REST API from Python, without using the official Python client.