# How to identify what version jar is running under ColdFusion

Tags: jar, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

How can I update the jar files to the latest version which comes with coldfusion installation? I can see jar files, with different versions, under different locations. How can I confirm which version of the jar is currently running and what are the locations ColdFusion looks for these jars?

For example, in **coldfusion\lib** I have these jars:

- commons-collections.jar
- commons-collections.3.1.jar
- commons-collections.3.2.jar

Then in another location **\Coldfusion\cfusion\lib**, I have:

- commons-collections.jar

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> what are the locations coldfusion looks for these jars

Generally, [ColdFusion searches the following locations](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec14231-7fe5.html) for jars:

- ColdFusion Class Path (See *ColdFusion Administrator > Server Settings > Java & JVM*).
- Default JVM class path
- Dynamic paths specified in [`THIS.javaSettings`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffd.html) (CF10+ only)

> what version of the jar in currently running

*Usually* you can [identify the source jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983839/determine-which-jar-file-a-class-is-from) by picking a class likely to exists all versions of that library and checking it with [Class.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29). For that specific library, [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) would probably be a good choice, since the API says it has existed since version 1.0.

```
 // Create instance
 testClass = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils").getClass();
 // Convert class name to format:  /path/to/TheClassName.class 
 className = "/"& replace( testClass.name, ".", "/", "all") &".class";
 // Display location, or "null" if unknown
 location = testClass.getResource( className );
 writeOutput(  isNull(location) ? "null" : location.toString());
```

The results will obviously vary, but with my ColdFusion 11 install, the above returns:

> org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.class
>   **jar:file:/c:/ColdFusion/cfusion/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar**!/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.class