# How do I register a ColdFusion callback and call it from a Java class?

Tags: java, websocket, coldfusion, java-websocket, lucee

I need to register a ColdFusion callback (using Lucee) that will be executed from within a Java class as follows:

(I stubbed out how I envision invoking the callback - in comments below)

```
package com.bonnydoonmedia.io;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft_10;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

import java.net.URI;

/*
 * author: Robert Munn
 * date: 3/15/15
 * 
 * WSClient.java
 * 
 * Simple extension of WebSocketClient by Too Tall Nate
 * 
 * based on example client at
 * 
 * https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket
 * 
 * License: Mozilla Public License 2.0
 * 
 */

public class WSClient extends WebSocketClient{

    public WSClient( URI serverUri , Draft_10 draft ) {
        super( serverUri, draft );
    }

    public WSClient( URI serverURI ) {
        super( serverURI );
    }

    public void connect(){
        super.connect();
    }

    public void send( String message ){
        super.send( message );
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen( ServerHandshake handshakedata ) {
        System.out.println( "opened connection" );
        System.out.println( "ready state : " + super.getReadyState() );
        /* INVOKE THE CALLBACK HERE LIKE:
        callback({
            "action": "onOpen",
            "data": {}
        });
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage( String message ) {
        System.out.println( "received: " + message );
        /* INVOKE THE CALLBACK HERE LIKE:
        callback({
            "action": "onMessage",
            "data": {
                "message": message
            }
        });
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose( int code, String reason, boolean remote ) {
        // The codecodes are documented in class org.java_websocket.framing.CloseFrame
        System.out.println( "Connection closed by " + ( remote ? "remote peer" : "us" ) );
        /* INVOKE THE CALLBACK HERE LIKE:
        callback({
            "action": "onClose",
            "data": {
            }
        });
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void onError( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // if the error is fatal then onClose will be called additionally
        /* INVOKE THE CALLBACK HERE LIKE:
        callback({
            "action": "onMessage",
            "data": {
            }
        });
        */
    }
}
```

Creating the "object" in ColdFusion looks like this (this already works):

```
// create the websocket client
uriObject = createObject( "java", "java.net.URI" ).init("ws://local.websockets");
wsClient = CreateObject("java", "WSClient").init(uriObject);
```

Now I need to register a callback, and I'm thinking it would be done like this:

```
function void wsCallback (data) {

    switch(data.action) {
        case "onOpen":
            break;
        case "onClose":
            break;
        case "onMessage":
            break;
        case "onError":
            break;
    }

};

wsClient.setCallback(wsCallback);
```

The question is, how do I do the last part (setting the callback in the class)?

Comment: Since it is an abstract class, try using the [CFCProxy](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html). Create CFC with the desired functions ("onClose", etcetera). Then inside your java class, create an instance of that component using coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy, and invoke the appropriate function, ie `CFCProxy yourInstance = new CFCProxy(cfcPath...); yourInstance.invoke("onClose", args)`.

Comment: Hmmm... I haven't used CFCProxy before. I'll have to investigate. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: (Edit) Should be pretty simple. Nothing special on the CF side. In java, just crate and instance with `new CFCProxy(cfcPath...)` and `invoke(...)` and you should be good to go :)

Comment: The examples I see use `import coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy;` but I'm not sure where that will be located when compiling java targeted for Lucee. Any ideas? (BTW, I'm not very skilled in Java)

Comment: My bad. I missed the Lucee tag. Since CFCProxy should already be in the core classpath, try [this tip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700231/how-to-identify-what-version-jar-is-running-under-coldfusion/37231805#37231805) to find out which jar contains that class. Just substitute `createObject("java", "coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy")` for the "testClass". I tried it with Lucee 4.5 Express, and it said it is located in the /lib/ext/lucee.jar

Comment: @Leigh - CFProxy seems to work nicely, but now I'm messing around with my class so that I can return a coldfusion struct, which I can't seem to figure out. If you have any ideas, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670241/how-do-i-return-a-coldfusion-struct-from-a-method-in-a-java-class-in-lucee. You can also answer this question and I'll be happy to accept the answer (at least until a better answer comes up! :)

Comment: Sure seems simple but I can't figure out how to create a Map, set the keys and return it. I was able to return a HashMap, which could probably work, but it's not a ColdFusion strict and doesn't show up like one.

Comment: *until a better answer comes up!* ... So we're going to the prom - unless your first choice says "yes" ;-) (Just joking).  Seriously though, looks like Lucee has other (cool) options for interacting with the CF engine. I would be very curious find out a Lucee guru's opinion on this one.  So if you find out more, do post it here. http://docs.lucee.org/guides/working-with-source/java-using-lucee-in-java.html

Comment: @Leigh - yea, I saw this article that looks really promising: http://docs.lucee.org/guides/working-with-source/java-using-lucee-in-java.html. Unfortunately, I was running Lucee 4.5, and the code examples on this article didn't work. So I decided to upgrade to 5, and now I'm completely F'ED!!! The upgrade didn't go smoothly at all, and I'm dead in the water for the time being.

Comment: Heh, looks like we both arrived at the same article.  Sorry to hear about the hosed install. Seems to be going around. I am trying to figure out why an app works only works on one out of two (theoretically) identical machines.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an abstract class, try using the [CFCProxy](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html). To use it create a CFC with the desired functions, ie "onClose", etcetera. Then inside your java class, import `coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy` and create an instance of that component. Then invoke the appropriate function, ie

```
CFCProxy yourInstance = new CFCProxy("c:/path/to/yourComponent.cfc");
yourInstance.invoke( "onClose", args );
```

The CFCProxy class should already be in the core class path. If you are not sure where to find it, try [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700231/how-to-identify-what-version-jar-is-running-under-coldfusion/37231805#37231805) to find out which jar contains that class. Just substitute `createObject("java", "coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy")` for the "testClass". I tried it with Lucee 4.5 Express, and it said it is located in `{luccee_root}/lib/ext/lucee.jar`.

**NB:** It looks like Lucee also has [other (cooler) options for interacting with the CF engine from java](http://docs.lucee.org/guides/working-with-source/java-using-lucee-in-java.html).