# How do I return a coldfusion struct from a method in a java class (in Lucee)?

Tags: java, struct, coldfusion, lucee

I am writing a java class and would like to return a coldfusion struct from a method. Struct extends Map and other things. I'm not a Java programmer, so I'm not sure how to fix this. [Here's the lucee java docs.](http://javadoc.lucee.org/)

When I try to compile the following code, I get an error saying that Struct is abstract and can't be instantiated (on the line when I try to create myStruct). I've tried to create a new Map, but that's also abstract.

```
import lucee.runtime.type;

public class MyClass {

    public lucee.runtime.type.Struct test () {

        // I was hoping to do this, but I get an error

        lucee.runtime.type.Struct myStruct = new lucee.runtime.type.Struct();
        myStruct.put("passed", true);

        return(myStruct);

    } // test()

}
```

Comment: (Edit) A Map is an interface (rather than an abstract class), but .. that is why you cannot create an instance of it. Something like a `HashMap` should be fine. Worked fine for me, so not sure what you mean by "does not show up like one". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Here the example I used: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/930ce66ce33910a573b3bf6bcd5706da

Comment: On my phone ATM, but you can get the Lucee creation util from the thread's page context and it will create CFML structs for you. The actual struct class is structimpl, but you can't create it directly since it's part of the loader and not in the core.  This page has a example if what you need. https://github.com/getrailo/railo/wiki/using_Railo_in_Java

Comment: @BradWood - since I'm using Lucee 5, I'm referencing this page: http://docs.lucee.org/guides/working-with-source/java-using-lucee-in-java.html. It's not very complete, especially for a non-Java programmer like me. I'm making progress but I haven't been able to create a new Component - `(Component) pc.loadComponent( cfcPath )` because the compiler doesn't recognize the "Component" symbol. I'm sure that means I have to import something, but I don't know what. How would I figure that out?

Comment: This question asks how to create a Struct, not a component.  To keep things on topic, I'd suggest adding an answer here that shows how you created your struct, or if it's still not working, post the specific error you're getting.  You should start a new SO question for calling a CFC, or ask on CFML Slack if you're looking for a more fluid discussion.

Comment: @BradWood, I was updating your link with the same one from Lucee 5, which doesn't seem to have changed very much, though there are some differences. I spent a few hours trying to get it running, but I had a heck of a time compiling it because it took a while to figure out what I needed to import. When I got it compiled, it throws an error because the CF engine isn't listening, which I think is because of the way I'm creating the class in CF. I agree that it's slightly off topic but if I could get it running, I could follow your suggestion to get CF to create the struct.