# How to get package data [jar file name] from stack trace?

Tags: java, scala, log4j, logback, stack-trace

In the [logback library](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html), they have a way to get "stack traces with packaging data" (package and package versions).

Example:

```
java.lang.Exception: 99 is invalid
  at path.to.MyClass.myFunc(MyClass.java:431) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
```

How do I get "`struts-1.2.9.jar`" from a line in a stack trace?

Is there a method in Java or Scala that does this?

```
String getPackageName(String lineInTrace) {
    ...
    return packageName
}
```

Comment: p.s. I totally saw  code like this online and then I lost it.

Comment: See [Determine which jar file a class is from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983839/determine-which-jar-file-a-class-is-from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for (StackTraceElement el : e.getStackTrace()) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(el.getClassName());
    String location = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString();
    System.out.println(location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') +1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stuff in the square brackets are the module name and version, in Java 9 and above. You can get the module name using `StackTraceElement.getModuleName()`.

It seems that if you are not using modules, the jar file name is used instead of the module name.