# Java dependency priority

Tags: java, dependency-management

Trying to figure out how will the JVM decide which dependency to use:

1. We have a `gradle` compiled fatJar, containing several dependencies, i.e. `Jackson` X version etc.
2. My app is a `Play framework 1.x` app, using the the fatJar artifact from stage 1, and other dependencies, including `aws java sdk` which uses `Jackson` itself, newer than X version.

How can I tell which `Jackson` version is used in runtime?
[It seems that on 1 env it uses the correct one, and on the other, `aws sdk` is using the incorrect `Jackson`]

Comment: You could use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983839/determine-which-jar-file-a-class-is-from) plus some additional logging if you're able to redeploy, just to confirm your theory.

Answer (score 1):

In simple case when you provide classpath to java and do not use any classloader the answer is simple. It will search classpath in order you provide.

I strongly discourage you from relying on that behavior.

There is solutions for you problem. One of them to use OSGi it allows to use multiple version of libraries, but i must mention that it is heavy framework.