# Running wrong guava version on oozie

Tags: apache-spark, guava, oozie

I am running a spark action on oozie. The spark application creates hive context.
Running with spark-submit works
I made sure that the jar that I run includes guava 14.0 version and on the sharelib of oozie its the same version and still I get the following error :

```
2018-01-21 15:04:56,753 [Driver] ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster  - User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.client(ClientWrapper.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runHive(ClientWrapper.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runSqlHive(ClientWrapper.scala:478)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:443)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at com.frontline.shopfloor.integration.Integration$.main(Integration.scala:46)
    at com.frontline.shopfloor.integration.Integration.main(Integration.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:552)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:214)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1560)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:587)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:781)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:325)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:281)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:239)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1069)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:359)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:768)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.<init>(BoneCPDataSource.java:64)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.BoneCPDataSourceFactory.makePooledDataSource(BoneCPDataSourceFactory.java:73)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:217)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
    ... 86 more
```

From where else the wrong guava version can be taken ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some code that identifies the location of the Guava with the wrong version and then you can change it with the compitable version.

Please check

[Determine which JAR file a class is from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983839/determine-which-jar-file-a-class-is-from)