# Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder not a subtype

Tags: java, java-17, jersey-client

I have a java 8 spark project using jersey client 2.36 and in the process of migrating to java 17. I changed all the places to have jakarta package and also updated jersey client to 3.1.0. However on running the project , I am getting error where the client is getting created.

currently I upgraded spark-core and spark-sql to 3.4.0 and springboot 3 and jakarta tp 3.X

ERROR:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder not a subtype
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1244)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
    at jakarta.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.lambda$findFirstService$1(FactoryFinder.java:178)
    at jakarta.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.findFirstService(FactoryFinder.java:187)
    at jakarta.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:114)
    at jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:62)
    at com.capitalone.customer.relationships.batch.impression.config.CustomerIdentifierApiConfig.setup(CustomerIdentifierApiConfig.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I have the dependency tree of jersey client as:

```
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:jar:3.1.0:compile
```

jersey client in jave:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, poolingReadTimeout);
        clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, poolingConnectTimeout);
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(poolingMaxTotal);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(poolingDefaultMaxPerRoute);
        clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);

        if (Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch(profile -> profile.contains("dev") || profile.equals("integration-test"))) {
            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslcontext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }

            }}, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            HostnameVerifier allowAll = (host, sslSession) -> true;
            client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig(clientConfig.getConfiguration()).sslContext(sslcontext).hostnameVerifier(allowAll).build();
```

this creation of client was working fine in earlier version( 2.36) with java 8. with the upgrade to jave 17 am getting  `Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder not a subtype'

is there any thing to be added to upgrade jersey client to 3.x?

complete pom file:

```
     com.customer.relationships.batch:impression:jar:3.3.0-RELEASE
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.reload4j:reload4j:jar:1.2.22:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:jar:8.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.univocity:univocity-parsers:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sketch_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql-api_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.12:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-vector:jar:12.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-format:jar:12.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-memory-core:jar:12.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:jar:1.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.arrow:arrow-memory-netty:jar:12.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:3.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.datasketches:datasketches-java:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.datasketches:datasketches-memory:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-core:jar:shaded-protobuf:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-shims:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.airlift:aircompressor:jar:0.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:17.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.threeten:threeten-extra:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-mapreduce:jar:shaded-protobuf:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-storage-api:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-column:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-common:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-encoding:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-format-structures:jar:1.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-jackson:jar:1.13.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm9-shaded:jar:4.23:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:1.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill_2.12:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-runtime:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-kvstore_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.crypto.tink:tink:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-common-utils_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:6.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.5.5-4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.9.45:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.roaringbitmap:shims:jar:0.9.45:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.12.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:jar:3.7.0-M11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:jar:3.7.0-M11:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.12:jar:3.7.0-M11:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.12:jar:3.7.0-M11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.96.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.96.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.96.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-aarch_64:4.1.96.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-aarch_64:4.1.96.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:jar:4.1.96.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.96.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:4.2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:4.2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:4.2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jmx:jar:4.2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.razorvine:pickle:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.10.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-crypto:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:6.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:6.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.10.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.10.9:compile
[INFO] +- com .api.customers:customers-relations-common:jar:2.0.0-RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-oauth-client:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com .chassis.starters:constants:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-log4j2-logger:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-jackson-adapters:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com .chassis.engine:chassis-jackson-adapters:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:6.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:6.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-business-model:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-encryption:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com .chassis.engine:chassis-secureddatum:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com .chassis.engine:chassis-spring-vault:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:endpoints-spi:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:json-utils:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:third-party-jackson-core:jar:2.20.74:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  \- software.amazon.eventstream:eventstream:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:jar:5.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |        +- org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5:jar:5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |        \- org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5-h2:jar:5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.162:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-converters:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-core-util:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-core-reflection:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com .chassis.engine:chassis-core-reflection:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com .chassis.engine:chassis-converters:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com .chassis.model:chassis-business-model:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jooq:jool:jar:0.9.15:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.8.22:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.8.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-model:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com .chassis.engine:chassis-model:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com .chassis.engine:chassis-constants:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-core-dao:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com .chassis.engine:chassis-core-dao:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com .chassis.engine:chassis-core-util:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20220320:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com .chassis.starters:chassis-spring-boot-starter-logging-profiling:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com .chassis.engine:chassis-logging-profiling:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com .chassis.engine:chassis-core-concurrency:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.11.3:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |     +- com .chassis:chassis-annotations:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com .chassis.engine:chassis-core-aop:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:32.0.1-android:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.77.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.77.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.77.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.77.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.77.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.77.Final:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:jar:4.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.datastax.oss:native-protocol:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-shaded-guava:jar:25.1-jre-graal-sub-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:jar:3.1.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.3.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-a64asm:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:jar:0.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-query-builder:jar:4.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-junit:jar:2.0.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:jar:2.0.0.0:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.0:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.8.0:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.24.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.0.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:jar:1.11.901:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.901:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.seratch:jslack:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.14.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.17.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.wildfly.openssl:wildfly-openssl:jar:1.0.7.Final:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.30:provided
[INFO] +- org.webjars:jquery:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty:hadoop-shaded-protobuf_3_7:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty:hadoop-shaded-guava:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.re2j:re2j:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.8.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-simplekdc:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-client:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerby-config:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-common:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     |  |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-crypto:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-util:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- org.apache.kerby:token-provider:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-admin:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |        +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-server:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |        |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerb-identity:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |        \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-xdr:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.55:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.21:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kerby:kerb-core:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-pkix:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     +- org.apache.kerby:kerby-asn1:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.apache.kerby:kerby-util:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO]    \- dnsjava:dnsjava:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: could not reproduce your issue, maybe try putting a breakpoint on ServiceLoader.java:1244
and check if value of `clazz.getSuperclass().getCanonicalName()` = "jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder"

Comment: @samabcde  clazz.getSuperclass().getCanonicalName() gives `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder`
not sure where this javx client builder is returned back instead of jakarta

Comment: This suggest you have older version of jersey-client in your classpath, could you include your pom.xml?

Comment: @samabcde I don't see older version of client in classpath. I have my pom file included

Comment: There are so many dependency, no really possible to reproduce in local.
Could you try follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983870/7928721 to find the class location by putting break point and debug?